# Logical matrix combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a $n$ x $m$ boolean matrix, Is there a formula that can give me the number of combinations for this matrix?

Also, I want to exclude the matrices that will have a column of all zeros, How can I calculate the combinations of the matrices that will have this condition ?

Comment: By "the number of combinations of this matrix", do you just mean the number of matrices with this condition? There are $2^{nm}$ boolean matrices, and then you can just perform inclusion-exclusion on the number of all-zero columns.

Comment: how can I perform inclusion-exclusion, sorry, my math skills are a bit low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that there are $2^{nm}$ boolean $n\times m$ matrices (each of the $nm$ entries can be $0$ or $1$). To exclude the ones with all zero columns, we perform inclusion exclusion. The idea of inclusion-exclusion is that for each column, we take out the number of boolean matrices that have all zeroes in that column, so we subtract those. However, we double counted- some matrices will all zeroes in both column 1 and column 2, and we subtract these matrices twice, once for column 1, and once for column 2, so we add these back. But then we may double count matrices with more all zero columns. This process of repeated subtraction and adding back is called inclusion-exclusion. The details are more nuanced, but this is the basic idea.

We have $m$ columns, and for each subset $X$ of $[m]=\{1,2\ldots m\}$, we want to know how many matrices have all zeroes in column $i$ for each $i\in X$. This is just $2^{n(m-|X|)}$, since all of the $m-|X|$ other columns can be anything. Furthermore, there are ${m\choose k}$ subsets of $[m]$ of size $k$. Then inclusion-exclusion just gives us $\sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}(-1)^k 2^{n(m-k)}$ as our answer.